# How to compute in Jama x for Ax = x

Tags: java, scala, matrix, jama

I want to calculate in Jama solution of equation `Ax = x` (where `A` is a matrix and `x` is a vector). If it was `Ax = b` it would look just like this:

```
Matrix x = A.solve(b);
```

The only think I thought of was something like this (written in `scala`):

```
var x = new Matrix(n, 1) // n is the number of rows
x = A.solve(x)
```

but it returns zeros, because `x` is initialized with zeros. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Hint: `Ax - x = 0` or `(A - E) x = 0`

Comment: Thanks, I just thought of it when I finished the post :)